# MVC6 TagHelper not disabling checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, tag-helpers

I have written a TagHelper called CanEditTagHelper that disables/enables input controls depending on a value passed in from the view.

The TagHelper looks like this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = CanEditAttribute)]
public class CanEditTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string CanEditAttribute = "asp-can-edit";

    [HtmlAttributeName(CanEditAttribute)]
    public bool CanEdit { set; get; }

    public CanEditTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (!CanEdit)
        {
            output.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
        }
        base.Process(context, output);
    }
}
```

And it is used in the view like so...

```
<input asp-for="UserName" asp-can-edit='Model.CanEditMember("UserName")' />
```

This works well for regular inputs but doesn't seem to work for CheckBoxes.  The disabled attribute is never added to the checkbox input.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label asp-for="Active" asp-context="label">
        <input asp-for="Active" 
               asp-can-edit='Model.CanEditMember("Active")'
               type="checkbox" />
            Active
    </label>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this tag helper doesn't add a disabled attribute to checkboxes?

Comment: what does `if (!CanEdit)` return ?

Comment: !CanEdit returns true because they cannot edit it, so it does go into the code where the disabled attribute is added.  Unfortunately, when the View is rendered, the checkbox doesn't have the disabled attribute..

Comment: What _bootstrap checkboxes_ are you referring to?

Comment: Disregard the bootstrap checkboxes note i made.  I was referring to how checkboxes are written with bootstrap but it doesn't matter if it's bootstrap or just a plain <input type="checkbox">.  It doesn't add the disabled attribute.

Comment: when you drop a breakpoint on that line that sets the disabled attribute, and inspect the attributes of output, is a disabled attribute listed?

Comment: Yes, the disabled attribute is being added to the list of attributes.